# Emojis in Rich Text Field

Tags: richtext

Does anyone know of a good way of handling emojis in a rich text field?

I'm aware that is possible to copy and paste them into one, but does anything along the lines of an emoji 'button' (i.e. to sit in the toolbar with a dropdown of categorised emojis) exist? Other suggestions welcome! Just keen to avoid the extra steps of having to find the emoji on an external source, copy, and paste in to the field.

A reference point would be [Slack's 'emoji menu'](https://get.slack.help/hc/en-us/articles/202931348-Emoji-and-emoticons).

Answer (score 3):

It looks like Redactor has a [plugin called “Clips”](https://imperavi.com/redactor/plugins/clips/) that allows you to:

> Create a dropdown of frequently used "snippets" of code, text, icons,
>   emoji, you name it.

Pixel and Tonic made it into [a plugin for Craft](https://github.com/pixelandtonic/RedactorClips) too.
<strike>I haven’t tried either but it looks like it should do the trick.</strike> I just tried the Craft plugin and it worked out pretty good. It doesn't have a preview of the emoji like Slack’s emoji menu though.

The plugin has settings where you can define the clips and the following HTML with each clip. Pretty straightforward.

[image: Clips plugin settings]

After installing it I edited one of the .json config files in `craft/config/redactor/` directory by adding

```
"plugins": ["clips"]
```

It then gives you a button on the tool bar called Clips. **Make sure your Rich Text field is set to use the config that you added this plugin to.**

[image: toolbar with Clips plugin installed]

Clicking that button gives you the following list. Clicking on a clip will insert the corresponding HTML

[image: Clips list in Rich Text field]

Not as polished as Slack’s emoji menu. Might be a way to edit the plugin to get it to do that though.

Comment: Thanks, this is really helpful! And thanks so much for the thorough explanation and screenshots. I do feel like this is still quite a way off from being a _complete_ solution for handling emojis in RTE fields (partly in terms of the limited number this could realistically handle without a large amount of per-project admin and also from a UI point of view, in terms of not seeing the actual emoji, and lots of scrolling), and also I'm _guessing_ from a look at Redactor Clips that if you were using it you could only define one clip set per site) so I won't mark 'accepted' but I've upvoted. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Windows and macOS support "emoji picker" palettes, out of the box:

- **Windows**: Press `Windows Key + .`
- **macOS**: Press `Control + Command + Space`
- **iOS**: Use the Emoji key in the bottom-left corner of your on-screen keyboard.